# grid.arrange of two plots with same y-axis scale

Tags: r

I want to have only one y-axis; however, both of the plots in this grid has a different position for the number 50. 
Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What's the code for plotting the figure? Normally you can do this by specifying the `ylim` option. At least in base. This seems like its made with ggplot2 so maybe have a look [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html)?

Comment: set the limits the same in both graphs before the grid.arrange, something like `+scale_y_continuous("E", limits = c(0,100)` but it would be easier to determine the problem if you shared code/data